# An html5 canvas element in the background of my page?

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to have a full screen canvas element in the background of a webpage and "normal" markup elements like a table in front of it?

like the following snippet (if it wouldn't be used as alternative content):

```
<canvas id="imageView" width="100%" height="100%">
    <table>...</table>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could try setting a CSS style on the canvas where it has a `position: fixed` (or `absolute` as appropriate), and then any content that **follows** it (as opposed to container content as you've given in your example) should sit on top of it.

Comment: tried style="position:fixed; top:0;left:0" and it works just fine. thanx!

Comment: just discovered that setting  z-index:-1;  is needed to put the canvas behind the other elements.

Comment: @fx42: Don't set `z-index: -1`, it messes with some browsers. Rather, wrap the rest of your elements in a div and set `z-index: 1` on that div.

Comment: @noinflection: Getting the same results as you: http://jsfiddle.net/zhZxM/1/ I'm assuming this wouldn't have been accepted if it didn't work though, perhaps try getting a response from @user306708 to see if there was something else s/he needed to do?

Comment: @noinflection: try z-index:-1 on the canvas.

Comment: @MatthewScharley: just came across this, but you need position relative/absolute on the div you set the z-index on(http://jsfiddle.net/BlessYAHU/zhZxM/132/).

Comment: I tried it in Chrome: `z-index: 1` only worked if position was set for both `<div>` and `<canvas>` (eg.: `position: fixed`)

Answer (score 11):

```html
<html>
  <style>
    body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    canvas{
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      z-index:-1;
    }
    div{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:0;
      left:12px;
      top:10px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
      Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <div>hello is floating div</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 600, 600);

      grd.addColorStop(0, "#FF0000");
      grd.addColorStop(1, "#00FF00");

      ctx.fillStyle = grd;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstyl u need js for canvas drawing.
          but u can attain a canvas element as background just by using CSS. try this script. and may serve ur need :)

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 8):

I tried it for you with the following code. The div gets placed on top of the canvas element just as Matthew describes it. So should work for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Canvas demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #canvasSection{ position:fixed;}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function draw()
    {
      //paint the text
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasSection');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
      context.fillStyle    = '#00f';
      context.font         = 'italic 30px sans-serif';
      context.textBaseline = 'top';
      context.font         = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
      context.strokeText('Your Text!!', 0, 0);

      //paint the square
      var canvasSquare = document.getElementById('canvasSquare');
      var ctxSquare = canvas.getContext('2d');

      ctxSquare.fillStyle='#FF0000';
      ctxSquare.fillRect(0, 100,50,100);
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="draw()">
    <canvas id="canvasSection">Error, canvas is not supported</canvas>
    <div>TestText</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to have it in pure JS separated from HTML

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas'),        
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
    size = c.width = c.height = 50;

for( var x = 0; x < size; x++ ){
    for( var y = 0; y < size; y++ ){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(0, 0%, ' + ( 100 - ( Math.random() * 15 ) ) + '%)';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
}

document.body.style.background = 'url(' + c.toDataURL() + ')';
```

```html
HTML on <b>canvas background</b>
```

Based on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/LCFxa)