# using an animated canvas as a background

Tags: html, css, canvas

So I have everything working perfectly and it looks nice, except that the canvas just takes up the entire screen and I cannot click on anything in the nav menu. I tried adding div tags around different things and changing the z-index but it doesnt change anything. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tvTheme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <canvas style="position: absolute;">Your browser does not support canvas, or you are blocking JavaScript from running</canvas>
    </div>
    <h1 style="position: absolute; padding-left: 3%;"> P F N </h1>
    <nav style="padding-top: 4%;">
        <a href="shows.php" style="color: white;"> Home </a>
        <a href="allShows.php"> TV Shows </a>
        <a href="tvAbout.php"> About </a>
        <a href="tvLegal.php"> Legal </a>
        <a href="tvFAQ.html"> FAQ </a>
        <a href=""> Bookmark </a>
    </nav>
    <div style='width: 100%;'>
        <form id="search" action="search.php" method=POST style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"\>
            <input type="text" name="term" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        //#dda56e
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var tau = 2 * Math.PI;

        function Triangle(canvs, cnt, sid, f) {
            this.phase = 0;
            this.ctx = canvs.getContext('2d');
            this.first = f;
            this.sides = sid;
            this.canv = canvs;
            this.draw = drawTriangle;
            this.size = screen.width/12;
            this.red = 221;
            this.green = 163;
            this.blue = 107;
        }

        function drawTriangle() {
            requestAnimationFrame(drawTriangle.bind(this));
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            var centerX = this.canv.width/10;
            var centerY = this.canv.height/7;
            this.phase += 0.005 * tau;

            if(this.first == 1) {
                this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
            }
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides; i++) {
                this.ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](
                    centerX + this.size * Math.cos(this.phase + i / this.sides * tau),
                    centerY + this.size * Math.sin(this.phase + i / this.sides * tau)
                );
            }
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+this.red+","+this.green+","+this.blue+",0.3)";
            this.red++;
            this.green-=.5;
            this.blue--;
            this.ctx.stroke();
            this.size--;
            if(this.size < 1) {
                this.size = 0;
            }
        }

        var collection = [];

        var triangle1 = new Triangle(canvas,context,3,1);
        triangle1.draw();

        var i = 0;
        function nextFrame() {
            if(i < 100000) {
                collection[i] = new Triangle(canvas,context,3,0);
                collection[i].draw();
                i++;
                setTimeout(nextFrame, 100);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(nextFrame, 0);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the canvas be behind all the elements on the page, but above the bodies background? I know that is really crappy worded so if you need a link to the site let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HTML Canvas as page background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043359/set-html-canvas-as-page-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` on the div containing your canvas.
See [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/)