# How to put p5.js canvas in a html div

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to add p5.js to the background of one section in my webpage. I am new to javascript and can't figure out how to bind the two parts together.

Answer (score 51):

You need to add code in your setup.

Make sure you have the function in a script tag in the html as well.
Note you do not add # in the .parent().

```
var myCanvas = createCanvas(winWidth, winHeight);
    myCanvas.parent("idnameofdiv");
```

Comment: @kimchoky lol what are the odds two people would use the same 3 year old problem in the same day

Comment: Your welcome :) I think it should be marked as the answer but OP disappeared. Still solving problems 5 years later haha glad p5.js didn't change their implementation.

Answer (score 6):

if you are inserting multiple p5js canvas in one page and are already using the form `new p5(sketch)`, you can just pass the id of your div as second parameter, like `new p5(sketch, idnameofdiv)`

Because the function sketch should be unique (if you don't use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/1391012)), I like to put the id in the name of the sketch function as well

```js
function sketch_idnameofdiv(p) {
  p.setup = function () {
    p.createCanvas(400,400);
  }

  p.draw = function () {
    // stuff to draw
  }
}
new p5(sketch_idnameofdiv, 'idnameofdiv')
```

if you don't need to insert multiple p5js canvas in one page, I guess you are looking for [Michael Paccione's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36540479/1391012)

Answer (score 5):

P5.js gives you an **html canvas** that you can use for positioning your sketch.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043359/set-html-canvas-as-page-background) is an example of using a canvas as the background of a div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        canvas {
           position:absolute;
           top:0;
           left:0;
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
           z-index:-1;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
    <script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas data-processing-sources="rectangles.pde"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is Processing.js instead of P5.js, but the idea is the same. Try googling something like "html canvas as background" for a ton of results. Try something out, and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 4):

To be more detailed about the answer:

`function setup()` is a function which executes ojnly once at the startup.

`function draw()` is a function which executes after setup() and it reloads on every frame of the picture.

The code goes like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>P5.js Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
  <script>
    function setup() {
      var canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
      canvas.parent('canvasForHTML');
    }

    function draw() {
      background(127);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Canvas for visualization</h1>
  <div id="canvasForHTML"></div>
  <p>Move your mouse around to see circles.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/74Ltdy8z/1/