# Add a P5.js sketch to a Bootstrap template background

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, p5.js

I am really new so my knowledge in general is really poor.

I am trying to add a P5js sketch into a Bootstrap template.

The ideal would be to be able to build a responsive design website, with some image and video galleries with a p5js code on the background.

I have done some tests using an example I found onine but I was not able to do it.

I attach the code here

https://codepen.io/llorencg/pen/LYVMLjZ

Any help will be apreciated !!

Thanks :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>p5 walkthrough</title> 
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.5/p5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">     
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-full bg-inverse" style="">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap and P5.js</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link to Nowhere</a>
        </li>
      </ul>          
    </nav>        
    <div class="container">
        <div id="jumbo-canvas" class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Fun With P5.js</h1>
          <p class="lead">P5 is a JavaScript library that can be used to draw things onto an html canvas. The P5 reference guide can be found <a href="https://p5js.org/reference/">here</a>, and legendary videos by Daniel Schiffman can be found <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvjgXvBlbQiydffZU7m1_aw">here.</a></p>
          <hr />
          <p>By giving this div an id of jumbo-canvas and and placing <code>canvas.parent('jumbo-canvas')</code>  in our setup function, we can draw inside this Bootstrap jumbotron.</p>
          <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Click this button for some truth</a>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an old thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043359/set-html-canvas-as-page-background) which seems to have the answer to your question, as I think [this](https://twgljs.org/) is what you mean.