# Set canvas element as background of a div element

Tags: css, html

We can use canvas for drawing custom shapes.
I need to draw my shape dynamically as a canvas item and place it for a div background item.
My pages generates run time and they aren't static html code so i can't use tricky methods.
What's your idea?

Regards

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719668/an-html5-canvas-element-in-the-background-of-my-page

Comment: @VimalStan I see this before but it's not clear for me :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you searching for [toDataURL()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html).

**UPD:**
Here a usage exaple:

```
dataUrl = your_canvas.toDataURL();
your_div.style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6t3xX/1/) on jsFiddle

Comment: Thank you for your reply , how should i use this?

Comment: Provide us with your HTML/JS. Or you want I wrote new page for you?

Comment: Could you make a sample please?

Comment: What if I want canvas animation as a background? That's now just one image.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need canvas2image: https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image

You can create a canvas and then get the contents as a png:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

....do stuff here...

var img = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Then all you need to do is use the png as a background image:

```
document.body.style.background = "url(" + img.src + ")";
```

Please correct me if any of this is wrong.