# Set canvas element as background of a div element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've found canvas animation using jquery plugin on [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Customizable-Interactive-Particles-Animation-with-jQuery-jParticle.html)

I want to display that animation plugin as background of a div element, i've found the answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011168/set-canvas-element-as-background-of-a-div-element) but i'm still confused how to implement **toDataURL()** method with jquery.

Or is there any other way how to set some animation plugins as background of a div element?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like neither of thoose requied what i wrote before. You just have to include the plugin and jquery library in the header like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="jparticle.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then call a jquery function on a container you want to run it:

```
$("body").jParticle({
});
```

If you wants to run it on a div instead of "body" just use "#id" on the function. Good luck :)

Comment: Please tell me if it's working :)

Comment: Yeah it work, i was try that method before. But absolutely i want to make it work as background of a div element like the answer link i was mention above

Comment: I edited it to the final version. Pretty simple. :) First src is your jquery.js file, can be downloaded as well in your directory with html file. The second is the plugin. Then you have to call the function between <script></script> tags.

Comment: $("#div").jParticle({}); will create a canvas element inside #div. i want to make the canvas element as a background element of #div, not as standalone canvas element inside a #div

Comment: You still can use the first option then. Make to divs. First is the plugin with z-index: 1; The second is your content with z-index: 2; You have to put your div's id instead of "body". Both divs are on the same position by positioning it with css(position: absolute; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height:100%;) And put both div-s in a 3. one that has a size, so both divs gonna take the 3. div's size and position.