# How to put p5 canvas into our div background?

Tags: p5.js

I would like to put p5js canvas in my divisions background.  How to do that?  I know how to put canvas in div but don't know how to put in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a P5.js question. It's more a general HTML and CSS question. I recommend googling something like [html use canvas as background of div](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+use+canvas+as+background+of+div) for a ton of results, including:

- [Use <canvas> as a CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background)
- [Set canvas element as background of a div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011168/set-canvas-element-as-background-of-a-div-element)
- [An html5 canvas element in the background of my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719668/an-html5-canvas-element-in-the-background-of-my-page)
- [Set HTML Canvas as page background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043359/set-html-canvas-as-page-background)

Taking a step back, it's worth noting that Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So you should really try to do some research and **write some code** and then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation.